# Tutte Berge formulaproblem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I have the following problem:
Let $G=(V,E)$, let $S\subset V$ be such that $\nu(G)=(|V|+|S|-oc(G-S))$. Now I need to prove that in a maximum matching, the nodes of $S$ are matched to nodes of different components of $G-S$. Now I know that the optimality certificate of the tutte berge is satisfied, but I can't seem to find a solution. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What does you $\nu $ mean?

Comment: As I remember : $\nu(G) = min (\frac{1}{2}(|V| + |U| - odd(G-U))$

Comment: @openspace Size of the maximal matching in $G$.

Comment: yes $\nu(G)$ is the maximum matching in our graph $G$.